# Perl - Encoding error when working with .html file

Tags: perl, encoding

I have some `.html` files in a directory to which I want to add one line of `css` code. Using `perl`, I can locate the position with a regex and add the `css` code, this works very well.

However, my first .html file contain an accented letter: **é** but the resulting `.html` file has an encoding problem and prints: **\xE9**

In the perl file, I have been careful to specify `UTF-8` encoding when opening and closing the files, has shown in the MWE below, but that does not solve the problem. How can I solve this encoding error?

**MWE**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec::Functions qw/ splitdir rel2abs /; # To get the current directory name

# Define variables
my ($inputfile, $outputfile, $dir);

# Initialize variables
$dir = '.';

# Open current directory
opendir(DIR, $dir);

# Scan all files in directory
while (my $inputfile = readdir(DIR)) {
    
    #Name output file based on input file
    $outputfile = $inputfile;
    $outputfile =~ s/_not_centered//;
    
    # Open output file
    open(my $ofh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $outputfile);

    # Open only files containning ending in _not_centered.html
    next unless (-f "$dir/$inputfile");
    next unless ($inputfile =~ m/\_not_centered.html$/);
    
    # Open input file
    open(my $ifh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $inputfile);
    
    # Read input file
    while(<$ifh>) {
        # Catch and store the number of the chapter
        if(/(<h2)(.*?)/) {
            # $_ =~ s/<h2/<h2 style="text-align: center;"/;
            print $ofh "$1 style=\"text-align: center;\"$2";
        }else{
            print $ofh "$_";
        }
    }
    
    # Close input and output files
    close $ifh;
    close $ofh;
}

# Close output file and directory
closedir(DIR);
```

**Problematic file named "Chapter_001_not_centered.html"**

```
<html > 
<head></head>
<body>
                                                           
<h2 class="chapterHead"><span class="titlemark">Chapter&#x00A0;1</span><br /><a id="x1-10001"></a>Brocéliande</h2>
Brocéliande

</body></html>
```

Comment: Is the HTML file encoded in UTF-8, or a different character set?

Comment: 0xe9 for é probably indicates that the HTML files aren't Unicode encoded but use some extended ASCII codepage like Windows-1252 (CP-1252) or ISO 8859-1 (ISO Latin-1). So UTF-8 won't help here.

Comment: Ah! I forgot to check. According to notepad++ it is in ISO 8859-1
Can I convert it?

Comment: By changing the encoding to open and close the files to ISO 8859-1, it solves the problem. If one of you wants to post the answer, I will validate it.

Comment: Re "*Can I convert it?*", Either convert it to what your program expects (UTF-8), or change your program to expect what it is (iso-8859-1)

Comment: Well, perhaps you have chosen a wrong approach. Why not use external CSS stylesheet to define a style for `h2.chapterHead` instead? Of course you need keep in mind that stylesheet should be included into all html documents of interest. Once you include stylesheet in all files of interest -- a simple change in stylesheet file itself will make changes in all files of the interest, you will not require to edit any html file at all.

Comment: @PolarBear @ikegami This question was already answered in the previous comments and I do not use a CSS stylesheet because my HTML is generated by `tex4ht`.

Comment: If you found an answer then post it as an answer below

Comment: In `Chapter_001_not_centered.html` file there is `class=` __CSS__ selector. Are you saying that it is included into the file for nothing or it accessed/used through `javascript`/`jQuery`/`jNode`? CSS simplifies structure of `HTML` file, makes it is easier to maintain, usage of `CSS` selectors is very convenient on programmatic level. On side note: you could use [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) instead [opendir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir) what would make your [perl](https://www.perl.org/) code simpler and two times shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question found an answer in the commments of @Shawn and @ sticky bit:

By changing the encoding to open and close the files to ISO 8859-1, it solves the problem. If one of you wants to post the answer, I will validate it.

Answer (score 1):

Following demo script does required **inject** with utilization of [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) function.

Note: the script creates a new file, uncomment rename to make replacement original file with a new one

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use open ":encoding(Latin1)";

my $dir = '.';

process($_) for glob("$dir/*_not_centered.html");

sub process {
    my $fname_in  = shift;
    my $fname_new = $fname_in . '.new';
    
    open my $in, '<', $fname_in
        or die "Couldn't open $fname_in";
        
    open my $out, '>', $fname_new
        or die "Couldn't open $fname_new";
        
    while( <$in> ) {
        s/<h2/<h2 style="text-align: center;"/;
        print $out $_;
    }
    
    close $in;
    close $out;

    # rename $fname_new, $fname_in
    #    or die "Couldn't rename $fname_new to $fname_in";

}
```

If you do not mind to run following script per individual file basis `script.pl in_file > out_file`

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print s/<h2/<h2 style="text-align: center;"/ ? $_ : $_ for <>;
```

In case if such task arises only occasionally then it can be solved with one liner

```perl
perl -pe "s/<h2/<h2 style='text-align: center;'/" in_file
```

Comment: Thank you but as indicated in the comments before your first comment, an answer was provided by Shawn and sticky bit

Comment: Your script has much not required code, this script demonstrates more concise approach.